# Multi-threaded downloading files with Guzzle HTTP client: EachPromises vs Pool objects

Tags: php, multithreading, http, guzzle

for testing purposes, I have an array of 2000 image URIs (strings) with I download asynchronously with this functions. After some googling & testing & trying I've come up with **2 functions that both of them work** (well to be honest *downloadFilesAsync2* throws a *InvalidArgumentException* at the last line).

The function *downloadFilesAsync2* is based on the class **GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise** and *downloadFilesAsync1* is based on the **GuzzleHttp\Pool** class.

Both functions download pretty well the 2000 files asynchronously, with the limit of 10 threads at the same time.

I know that they work, but nothing else. I wonder if someone could explain both aproaches, if one is better than the other, implications, etc.

```
// for the purpose of this question i've reduced the array to 5 files!
$uris = array /
  "https://cdn.enchufix.com/media/catalog/product/u/n/unix-48120.jpg",
  "https://cdn.enchufix.com/media/catalog/product/u/n/unix-48120-01.jpg",
  "https://cdn.enchufix.com/media/catalog/product/u/n/unix-48120-02.jpg",
  "https://cdn.enchufix.com/media/catalog/product/u/n/unix-48120-03.jpg",
  "https://cdn.enchufix.com/media/catalog/product/u/n/unix-48120-04.jpg",
);

function downloadFilesAsync2(array $uris, string $dir, $overwrite=true) {
    $client   = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $requests = array();
    foreach ($uris as $i => $uri) {
        $loc = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($uri);
        if ($overwrite && file_exists($loc)) unlink($loc);
        $requests[] = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $uri, ['sink' => $loc]);
        echo "Downloading $uri to $loc" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $pool = new \GuzzleHttp\Pool($client, $requests, [
        'concurrency' => 10,
        'fulfilled' => function (\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response, $index) {
            // this is delivered each successful response
            echo 'success: '.$response->getStatusCode().PHP_EOL;
        },
        'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
            // this is delivered each failed request
            echo 'failed: '.$reason.PHP_EOL;
        },
    ]);
    $promise = $pool->promise();  // Start transfers and create a promise
    $promise->wait();   // Force the pool of requests to complete.
}

function downloadFilesAsync1(array $uris, string $dir, $overwrite=true) {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $promises = (function () use ($client, $uris, $dir, $overwrite) {
        foreach ($uris as $uri) {
            $loc = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($uri);
            if ($overwrite && file_exists($loc)) unlink($loc);
            yield $client->requestAsync('GET', $uri, ['sink' => $loc]);
            echo "Downloading $uri to $loc" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    })();
    (new \GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise(
        $promises, [
        'concurrency' => 10,
        'fulfilled'   => function (\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response) {
            //            echo "\t=>\tDONE! status:" . $response->getStatusCode() . PHP_EOL;
        },
        'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) {
            echo 'ERROR => ' . strtok($reason->getMessage(), "\n") . PHP_EOL;
        },
    ])
    )->promise()->wait();
}
```

Comment: Is the `downloadFilesAsync2` method a copy of what you tested?  If so, I believe I can provide an explanation for the InvalidArguementExemption.

Comment: Sorry, Im not sure to understand your question. Of course, `downloadFilesAsync2` is an exact copy &paste of the method I tested. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will address the *InvalidArgumentException* within the `downloadFilesAsync2` method.  There are actually a pair of issues with this method.  Both relate to this:

`$requests[] = $client->request('GET', $uri, ['sink' => $loc]);`

The first issue is the fact that `Client::request()` is a synchronous utility method which wraps `$client->requestAsync()->wait()`.  `$client->request()` will return an instance of `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface`, as a result `$requests[]` will actually be populated with `ResponseInterface` implementations.  This is what, ultimately causes the *InvalidArgumentException* as the `$requests` does not contain any `Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface`'s, and the exception is thrown from within `Pool::__construct()`.

A corrected version of this method should contain code which looks more like:

```
$requests = [
    new Request('GET', 'www.google.com', [], null, 1.1),
    new Request('GET', 'www.ebay.com', [], null, 1.1),
    new Request('GET', 'www.cnn.com', [], null, 1.1),
    new Request('GET', 'www.red.com', [], null, 1.1),
];

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests, [
    'concurrency' => 10,
    'fulfilled' => function(ResponseInterface $response) {
        // do something
    },
    'rejected' => function($reason, $index) {
        // do something error handling
    },
    'options' => ['sink' => $some_location,],
]);

$promise = $pool->promise();
$promise->wait();
```

To answer your second question, "What is the difference between these two methods", the answer is simply, there is none.  To explain this, let me copy and paste `Pool::__construct()`:

```
/**
 * @param ClientInterface $client   Client used to send the requests.
 * @param array|\Iterator $requests Requests or functions that return
 *                                  requests to send concurrently.
 * @param array           $config   Associative array of options
 *     - concurrency: (int) Maximum number of requests to send concurrently
 *     - options: Array of request options to apply to each request.
 *     - fulfilled: (callable) Function to invoke when a request completes.
 *     - rejected: (callable) Function to invoke when a request is rejected.
 */
public function __construct(
    ClientInterface $client,
    $requests,
    array $config = []
) {
    // Backwards compatibility.
    if (isset($config['pool_size'])) {
        $config['concurrency'] = $config['pool_size'];
    } elseif (!isset($config['concurrency'])) {
        $config['concurrency'] = 25;
    }

    if (isset($config['options'])) {
        $opts = $config['options'];
        unset($config['options']);
    } else {
        $opts = [];
    }

    $iterable = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\iter_for($requests);
    $requests = function () use ($iterable, $client, $opts) {
        foreach ($iterable as $key => $rfn) {
            if ($rfn instanceof RequestInterface) {
                yield $key => $client->sendAsync($rfn, $opts);
            } elseif (is_callable($rfn)) {
                yield $key => $rfn($opts);
            } else {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Each value yielded by '
                    . 'the iterator must be a Psr7\Http\Message\RequestInterface '
                    . 'or a callable that returns a promise that fulfills '
                    . 'with a Psr7\Message\Http\ResponseInterface object.');
            }
        }
    };

    $this->each = new EachPromise($requests(), $config);
}
```

now if we compare that to an a simplified version of the code within the `downloadFilesAsync1` method:

```
$promises = (function () use ($client, $uris) {
    foreach ($uris as $uri) {
        yield $client->requestAsync('GET', $uri, ['sink' => $some_location]);
    }
})();
(new \GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise(
    $promises, [
    'concurrency' => 10,
    'fulfilled'   => function (\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response) {
        // do something
    },
    'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) {
        // do something
    },
])
)->promise()->wait();
```

In both examples, there is a generator which yields promises that resolve to instances of `ResponseInterface` and that generator along with the configuration array (fulfilled callable, rejected callable, concurrency) is also fed into a new instance of `EachPromise`.

In summary:

1. `downloadFilesAsync1` is functionally the same thing as using `Pool` only without the error checking that has been built into `Pool::__construct()`.
2. There are a few errors within `downloadFilesAsync2` which will cause the files to be downloaded in a synchronous fashion prior to receiving an *InvalidArgumentException* when the `Pool` is instantiated.

My only recommendation is: use whichever feels more intuitive for you to use.

Comment: First of all, many thanks for your time in writing the answer, its not an easy matter. I've made your adjustments (look my changes at downloadFilesAsync2) and it removes the InvalidArgumentException (and function executes aparently ok) but the files are not downloaded.